# Depth Buffer in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw a series of rectangles using OpenGL but some of the ones that should appear below a rectangle appear above it.

To enable the depth function I am using

```
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

I am using gluLookAt at the begining of each draw. Here is an image of the problem. The blue rectangles are positioned with higher y values than the green rectangles.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the top image some of the green rectangles appear above the blue ones. Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to fix it? Could it have something to do with the order that I'm drawing the rectangles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you clear your colour buffer are you also clearing the depth buffer?

`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Are you sure the image isn't correct? Some of those green squares actually
do look higher than the blue ones.

Answer (score 7):

Did you enable the depth buffer in whatever windowing system you are using?  For example, using glut you might need to:  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | ....);

Comment: I am using qt for my windowing toolkit. I am not aware of any function like that. Do you know if there is one I should be calling simmilar to glut's function.

Comment: In the `QGLFormat` object, you should be able to check if the depth buffer is enabled with the `depth` and `setDepth` methods.